# Django Rest Framework custom user model PUT Request

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, put

I'm having trouble while sending `PUT` request for my custom user model

On sending PUT request to `/api/provider/1/`, where `1` is `pk`, with put data `phone_number = 1234567890` I get `{"email": ["This field is required."] }`

If I send `email` and `phone_number`, I get `{"email": ["Provider with this email already exists."]}`

**Model**

```
class ProviderManager(BaseUserManager):

    def _create_user(self, email, password, is_staff, is_superuser, **extra_fields):
        '''Creates and saves a User with the given email and password'''
        now = timezone.now()

        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Email can\'t be empty')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, is_active=True, is_superuser=is_superuser,
                          is_staff=is_staff, last_login=now, date_joined=now,
                          **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password, phone_number, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields['phone_number'] = phone_number
        return self._create_user(email, password, False, False, **extra_fields)

    def create_user(self, email, password, phone_number, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields['phone_number'] = phone_number
        return self._create_user(email, password, True, True, **extra_fields)


class Provider(AbstractBaseUser):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, default='')
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=256, unique=True, db_index=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=8, default='')
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=8, default='')

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['phone_number',]

    objects = ProviderManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'user'
        verbose_name_plural = 'users'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.name

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.name

    def email_user(self, subject, message, from_email=None, **kwargs):
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email])
```

**Serializer**

```
class ProviderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'email', 'phone_number', 'language', 'currency',)
```

**View**

```
@api_view(['GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
def provider_detail(request, provider_id):
    '''Read, update or delete a provider'''
    try:
        provider = User.objects.get(pk=provider_id)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    print('GOT PROVIDER ' + provider.email)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        serializer = ProviderSerializer(provider)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'PUT':
        serializer = ProviderSerializer(provider, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        provider.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Answer (score 2):

When doing a PUT you need to submit all the fields for the model only a PATCH would allow you to update by passing one field

Answer (score 0):

There is `partial` parameter which you can pass to serializer, to indicate, that it is a partial update.

From the doc:
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#partial-updates